# Why it is necessary to put expression to quotes (or dblquotes)

Tags: grep

When greping like this

```
cat .bashrc | grep '\.b'
# .bashrc
```

Grep returns correct data, but why are those quotes necessary?

Comment: You should never execute that command, you should execute `grep -F '.b' .bashrc` instead. Get the book "Shell Scripting Recipes" by Chris Johnson.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `\` character is special to the shell, if you want to pass a `\` to grep, you need to wrap or escape the `\` so the shell does not do its normal interpretation of the `\`.

When you type in a line of text, it first goes to the shell, which parses it, extracting command names and arguments and special commands and pipelines and redirects and variables and all kinds of things.  Once the shell has done all its interpretation and transformation of what you typed in, it runs the commands it found with the arguments it found.

In your case, you want to run the command `grep` with the argument `\.b` -- the `\` to tell grep to match a lteral `.` instead of any character.  But if you just typed `\.b` as the argument, the shell would interpret that `\` as meaning "ignore any special meaning of the next character" and pass the argument `.b` to `grep`.  So you need to escape the `\` so the shell will not do that.  You can do that with quotes (like you did), or with another `\` -- if you enter `grep \\.b` then the first `\` will escape the second `\` and it will pass `\.b` to grep.